# How do i add slash commands discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

So i followed [Codelyon](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC08G-UJT58SbkdmcOYyOQVw)'s [Code Your Own Discord Bot 2021](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_sD9udZnCk&list=PLbbLC0BLaGjpyzN1rg-gK4dUqbn8eJQq4) playlist on youtube and i used his advanced command handler and updated it a little bit by modifying/adding my own commands but then i would like to change his regular advanced command handler with **slash** commands but i have no idea how to implement it. I've watched some other tutorials but they don't seem to work. Hopefully someone can help me out.

Code of the main.js file:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: ['GUILDS', 'GUILD_MESSAGES']
});

const prefix = '!';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online!');
});

client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (!client.commands.get(command)) return;

    client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args, Discord, prefix, client);
})

client.login('xxx');
```

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw4As.png) is my file format

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this should get you started then use this guide for making the commands

[DiscordJS Guide - Slash Commands](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#registering-slash-commands)

You will also need to make sure that you go to [Discord Dev](https://discord.dev) and make sure that your bot is invited to your guild with these checked under the OAuth2 tab and set your permissions needed

[image: Discord Dev]

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: ['GUILDS', 'GUILD_MESSAGES']
});

const prefix = '!'; //*

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection(); //*
client.slashCommands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));//*
// create a new folder for your slash commands
const slashCommandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./slashCommands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) { //*
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);//*
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);//*
}//*
// delete anything using "commands" if you only plan on having slash commands otherwise keep both ( I marked them with a //* )

for (const file of slashCommandFiles) {
    const slashCommand = require(`./slashCommands/${file}`);
    client.slashCommands.set(slashCommand.name, slashCommand);
}

// other code

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (interaction.isCommand()) {
        const command = client.slashCommands.get(interaction.commandName);

        try {
            command.execute(client, interaction);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
                
        }

    }
    if (interaction.isButton()) {
        
    }
    if (interaction.isContextMenu()) {

    }
});
```

Comment: thanks but, someone already told me to look through the documentation and i did make the slash commands working without any help!